# How do I (SELECT) populate two objects from two tables with a single query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, multiple-tables

This should be something encountered by programmers often, but I never tried to get things this way.

That is, I'll explain. Say, I need to fetch values from table Zoo like this:

```
 @"SELECT z.predator, z.prey FROM Zoo AS z WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore"
```

Now I can get all the values to a List. I need to display the details of that querying in a grid. Now having got z.predator and z.prey values (which are for time sake integers, ie, their respective ids), I need to populate its meaningful values for displaying it to end user (I can't just display their ids). So now I might do something like this:

```
 foreach (Zoo z in lstZoo)
 {
       Animal predator = GetFromAnimalTable(z.Predator)
       Animal prey = GetFromAnimalTable(z.Prey)
 }
```

This can make the program slower. Can I query all the details in one go? Something like this:

```
   SELECT (SELECT * FROM ANIMAL WHERE id=z.predator), 
          (SELECT * FROM ANIMAL WHERE id=z.prey) 
   FROM Zoo AS z WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore
```

Provided I can read the values to a new bigger object? Or is this considered a bad practice?

**UPDATE:** Is it a standard practice to do this? Or is it recommended to individually populate as I stated first?

**UPDATE 2**: I seem to have made a terrible mistake of not posting the query exactly as I needed. I thought I could tweak the answers from here to meet my requirement, alas no with the parenthesis construction of Access queries.

Here is how my actual query would be:

```
SELECT z.predator, p.lifeSpan, z.prey 
FROM Zoo AS z 
INNER JOIN Plants AS p ON p.parent_id=z.id 
WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore
```

Actually I had an INNER JOIN query already with another table. Now I need to get (SELECT) values of z.predator (and its corresponding values from Animals table), p.lifeSpan, z.prey (and its corresponding values from Animal table) meeting the INNER JOIN and WHERE condition.

A pseudo code would look like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM ANIMAL WHERE id=z.predator), p.lifeSpan, (SELECT * FROM ANIMAL WHERE id=z.prey) 
FROM Zoo AS z INNER JOIN Plants AS p ON p.parent_id=z.id 
WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore
```

It should be pretty easy to extend my requirement from the answers here, but no success till now. I tried:

```
SELECT a1.*, p.lifeSpan, a2.* 
FROM Zoo AS z 
INNER JOIN Plants AS p ON p.parent_id=z.id 
INNER JOIN Animal AS a1 ON (a1.id=z.predator)
INNER JOIN Animal AS a2 ON (a2.id=z.prey)
WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore
```

And many variants of this with and without brackets. How can the above query be properly structured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this your latest query attempt:

```
SELECT a1.*, p.lifeSpan, a2.* 
FROM Zoo AS z 
INNER JOIN Plants AS p ON p.parent_id=z.id 
INNER JOIN Animal AS a1 ON (a1.id=z.predator)
INNER JOIN Animal AS a2 ON (a2.id=z.prey)";
WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore
```

Discard the semicolon from inside the statement.  Also discard the double quote.

Just to simplify the SQL, exclude the WHERE clause for now.

Then you should be in a better position to address the issue of parentheses which Access' db engine requires for multiple joins.

```
SELECT a1.*, p.lifeSpan, a2.* 
FROM
    ((Zoo AS z 
    INNER JOIN Plants AS p ON p.parent_id=z.id) 
    INNER JOIN Animal AS a1 ON a1.id=z.predator)
    INNER JOIN Animal AS a2 ON a2.id=z.prey
```

Notice I discarded those parentheses which enclosed the ON expressions.  Simple ON expressions don't require them.  If you had a compound expression for ON, then you would need parentheses like this:

```
ON (p.parent_id=z.id AND p.foo = z.bar)
```

The sample query I suggested looks correct to me.  (If it works for you, add your WHERE clause back again.)  However, I don't pay close attention to parentheses placement because I use Access' query designer to set up joins ... and it adds the parentheses the db engine requires.

I urge you to do the same.  If you're using an Access db from Dot.Net without having a copy of Access installed, you really should get a copy.  Trying to use a database without that database's native development tools is an unreasonable challenge ... somewhat like trying to type while wearing mittens.

Comment: to be honest, I asked you to help me after seeing your profile. You seem to be an access specialist :D

Comment: The double quote and semicolon thing, its a typo obviously.. Yeah I would use the query designer. Is it that query wizard you are talking about? I have used wizards before, not sure if that is what you mean by this..

Comment: omG it just worked :D One question, is it a standard practice to query multiple objects like this with one query?

Comment: Yes, queries which join multiple data sources are common.  In a normalized database, your data will be spread among multiple tables.  Then join the tables in queries to view related data.  If this is new to you, see if this page helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Mm, I usually write different queries to populate each object (ie of objects of each table)

Comment: the link you gave me doesnt answer to the point I made. I of course normalize databases (who doesnt atleast try, thats the very basic concept of relational databases). That is exactly why my data is spread across tables. My question which is more a standard practice, to populate animal objects along with zoo objects or first get the zoo objects, and then run a separate query to populate the properties of animal objects from the animal.id we get with the zoo objects? I had always gone for the latter approach which later became slower as data increased.

Comment: I misunderstood.  My standard practice is to retrieve all related objects with one query operation whenever practical.  I avoid retrieving individual objects with separate queries, then associating them in the application.  If that still doesn't address what you're asking, consider submitting a new question.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT pred.col1 AS PredCol1, ..., pred.colx AS PredColx, 
       prey.col1 AS PreyCol1, ..., prey.colx AS PreyColx
    FROM Zoo z
        INNER JOIN Animal pred
            ON z.predator = pred.id
        INNER JOIN Animal prey
            ON z.prey = prey.id
    WHERE z.preyType = @carnivore
```

Alternatively, you might want something like this instead.

```
SELECT 'Predator' AS AnimalType, pred.*
    FROM Zoo z
        INNER JOIN Animal pred
            ON z.predator = pred.id
    WHERE z.preyType = @carnivore
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Prey' AS AnimalType, prey.*
    FROM Zoo z
        INNER JOIN Animal prey
            ON z.prey = prey.id
    WHERE z.preyType = @carnivore
```

Comment: Just change the SELECT to `pred.PredatorName, prey.PrayName`

Comment: His answer changed after I posted the comment but anyways, if you only need to display the name of the animals u don't need to `SELECT *`, just take the fields u need, it might ease a bit the network transfer.

Comment: @PedroC88: As always, I reserve the right to fix my own boneheaded omissions and errors at any time. :-)

Comment: @PedroC88 Yes, But I do want all the fields, not just the name, so doesnt matter.

Comment: @nawfal using all fields as * is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli no worries there, I was just stating, and your corrections do make for a better answer :)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Can you see my updated query in question? Some bracket syntax issue it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Joining the tables

```
SELECT aPrey.Name as PreyName, aPredatior.Name as PredatorName 
FROM Zoo AS z 
LEFT JOIN Animal AS aPrey On aPrey.id= z.prey
LEFT JOIN Animal AS aPredatior On aPredatior.id= z.predator
WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore
```

Comment: Also take into account that in this query you might need to account for DBNULL as aPrey.Name and aPredator.Name, unless you have properly created the Foreign Keys to the `Animal` table.

Comment: That query has 2 joins.  Access' db engine will reject it because it demands parentheses with more than 1 join.

Comment: @HansUp how would the parentheses be placed in the above code? I have trouble getting that code working.

Comment: Use Access' query designer to build the joins ... it will add the needed parentheses to keep the db engine happy.  If you don't have Access available, try this: `SELECT aPrey.Name as PreyName, Predatior.Name as PredatorName FROM (Zoo AS z LEFT JOIN Animal AS aPrey On aPrey.id= z.prey) LEFT JOIN Animal AS aPredatior On aPredatior.id= z.predator WHERE z.preyType=@carnivore`

Comment: Thanks @HansUp, let me try that :)

Comment: @HansUp Can you see my updated query in question? Some bracket syntax issue it seems..