# Gridview and Select query

Tags: c#

I am working with gridview and tables, I am using c# and asp.net. Assuming I have 2 tables, lets just name it Profiles and Info.

In table profiles let's say I have fields with p_Id, FirstName, LastName and in Transaction I have I_Id, childsID, fathersID, mothersID.

This is what my tables looks like:

Profile

```
| p_Id | FirstName | LastName |

| 1    | Jack      | Cole     | 
| 2    | Cynthia   | Cole     | 
| 3    | Robert    | Cole     |
```

Info

```
| I_Id | childsID | fathersID | mothersID |

| 1    | 1        | 3         | 2         |
```

Now in my gridview I have to display FirstName, LastName, Father and Mother. But I need to display their names not their ID's.

For now my gridview looks like this:

```
First Name | Last Name | Father| Mother |

Jack       | Cole      | 3     | 2      |
```

what I want is like this:

```
First Name | Last Name | Father      | Mother       |

Jack       | Cole      | Robert Cole | Cynthia Cole |
```

Comment: Generate another temporary table that you want as output. In this temp table, fill in value of Names in place of ID by traversing the original table (this is for the case when you have less data).

Comment: You're missing something about `Join`. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842729/how-do-i-select-populate-two-objects-from-two-tables-with-a-single-query) for a reference. To help you further, you should show us your query..

Comment: have a look in this site [link]http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/bind-mult-table-gridview-asp4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select p.firstName, p.LastName
   , (select sp.FirstName+' '+sp.Lastname FROM profile sp WHERE sp.p_id=i.fathersid) as father
   , (select sp.FirstName+' '+sp.Lastname FROM profile sp WHERE sp.p_id=i.mothersid) as mother
from info i
inner join profile p ON (p.p_id=i.childsID)
```